# Access VBA - if record does not exist then insert to another table

Tags: ms-access, vba

Completely new to Access VBA so please be nice!

I have tblNew and tblTeam.

I want to loop through each record in tblNew to check if it already exists in tblTeam. The identifier is the email address. If the record does not exist then I want to add the record to tblX.

I'm stuck on searching to check if the record exists and how to loop through each record in the tblNew.

Apologies if I've duplicated any questions, I really couldn't understand or find what I was looking for.

Comment: Are you searching to see if the entire record is in tblTeam, or just the unique identifier of EmailAddress?

Comment: Don't "Loop" through a table. That is an absolute last resort. Instead get a "Set" that matches your definition `SELECT tblNew.emailAddress FROM tblNew LEFT OUTER JOIN tblTeam ON tblNew.emailAddress = tblTeam.EmailAddress WHERE tblTeam.EmailAddress IS NULL GROUP BY emailAddress` that will give you a list of distinct email address in `tblNew` that isn't `tblTeam` already. Now stick `INSERT INTO tblX (emailAddress) <that same SELECT statement>` to insert them all at once. No loops and just on SQL statement will do this.

Answer (score 2):

VBA is not necessarily required for this task - it can be quite easily achieved using an `INSERT` statement (aka Append Query), for example:

```
INSERT INTO tblX
SELECT 
    tblNew.*
FROM    
    tblNew LEFT JOIN tblTeam ON tblNew.EmailAddress = tblTeam.EmailAddress
WHERE 
    tblTeam.EmailAddress IS NULL
```